# How to pass schema to rdd dynamically in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe that consists of text column and doing some operations on that. I am converting the dataframe to rdd and doing other operation but when I am converting rdd back to pyspark dataframe, it is expecting a schema. I have passed the schema as well but it is not working.

Below is the dataframe:

```
temp = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "Julia is awesome"),
    (1, "I wish Java-DL could use case-classes!@#$"),
    (2, "Data-science is  cool"),
    (3, "Machine")
], ["id", "words"])
```

Below is the schema:

```
print(temp.schema)

StructType(List(StructField(id,LongType,true),StructField(words,StringType,true)))
```

Performing a regex transformation on words column

```
temp_1 = temp.withColumn('words', F.regexp_replace('words', r'(\s)+', '$1'))
```

I am converting the pyspark dataframe to rdd below

```
rdd_df = temp_1.rdd.map(lambda x: ' '.join(x['words']))
```

Converting the rdd back to spark dataframe

```
result_df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd_df, schema = temp.schema)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'J u l i a   i s   a w e s o m e' in type <class 'str'>
```

Comment: `rdd_df` will only have 1 element as per the `map()`

Comment: @samkart It means the rdd_df consists of only one column i.e; words? Can you tell me how to achieve this so that all columns has to present in the final dataframe?

Comment: u can have a look at my Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# rdd_df = temp_1.rdd.map(lambda x: ' '.join(x['words']))
rdd_df = temp_1.rdd.map(lambda x: [' '.join(x['words'])])
# Only words left After ur rdd.map.
spark.createDataFrame(rdd_df, ['words']).show(10, False)
# OR
rdd_df.toDF(['words']).show(10, False)

#+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|words                                                                            |
#+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|J u l i a   i s   a w e s o m e                                                  |
#|I   w i s h   J a v a - D L   c o u l d   u s e   c a s e - c l a s s e s ! @ # $|
#|D a t a - s c i e n c e   i s   c o o l                                          |
#|M a c h i n e                                                                    |
#+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


rdd_df = temp_1.rdd.map(lambda x: [x['id'], ' '.join(x['words'])])
spark.createDataFrame(rdd_df, temp.schema).show(10, False)
#+---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|id |words                                                                            |
#+---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|0  |J u l i a   i s   a w e s o m e                                                  |
#|1  |I   w i s h   J a v a - D L   c o u l d   u s e   c a s e - c l a s s e s ! @ # $|
#|2  |D a t a - s c i e n c e   i s   c o o l                                          |
#|3  |M a c h i n e                                                                    |
#+---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```